# Crash while trying to concatenate two strings

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

char *concat(char *string1,char *string2)
{
          char *stringfinal=new char[strlen(string1)+strlen(string2)+2];
          stringfinal=string1;
          char *dest=new char[strlen(string1)+strlen(string2)+2];
          dest = stringfinal;
          while(*dest != '\0')
          {
                      dest++;
          }

          *dest=' ';  // Point 1


          while(*string2 != '\0')        
               *dest++=*string2++;  //Point2
          *dest='\0';
          return stringfinal; 

}

int main()
{

    char *str1="Anurag";
    char *str2="Jain";

    char *strfinal = new char[strlen(str1)+strlen(str2)+2];
    strfinal=concat(str1,str2);

    cout<<strfinal;
    cin.get();

}
```

Comment: Is this homework? It should have the homework tag.

Comment: There are a number of things wrong here, including the fact that you do three new[] allocations when you only need one.  What is the difference between stringfinal and dest in your concat function?

Comment: @Brian - didn't the homework tag get removed by Jeff-it's-not-me-it's-the-community-Atwood about a year ago?

Comment: @Will - Er ... no, not at all. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/homework

Comment: @Brian - thanks for that - I assumed it had died in the purge of 'meta' tags: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/ but it appears it was somehow exempted.  I think my account is set to ignore posts tagged 'homework' which is why I hadn't realised it was still in use.

Comment: Yeah, reading through meta it seems Jeff is on the fence but for now it's still being used.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that you seem to think that

```
stringfinal=string1
```

and

```
dest = stringfinal;
```

are doing string copies, whereas they're actually just reasigning the `dest` and `stringfile` pointers to point somewhere else (and immediately losing the memory you've just new'd).

You probably want `strcpy(stringfile, string1)` instead.

Even with this error fixed, this not really a very shining example of the way people write C++ nowadays.  You would almost certainly be better-off using std::string, which would do all this string/pointer/allocation stuff properly for you, leaving you to think about more important stuff.

But if you're just trying to understand what's behind built-in string classes, then more power to you...

Comment: No, he probably don't want strcpy but std::string. :-)

Comment: thanks...but if I want answer in format "Anurag Jain"???

Answer (score 3):

The first problem that I see is the second line here:

```
char *stringfinal=new char[strlen(string1)+strlen(string2)+2];
stringfinal=string1; //problematic line
```

First you allocate memory and the variable `stringfinal` holds this memory. And then you overwrite this variable with the memory held by `string1`. Your newly allocated memory gone, and the problem starts right from here, the second line.

And similar mistake here also:

```
char *dest=new char[strlen(string1)+strlen(string2)+2];
dest = stringfinal;
```

The newly allocated memory held by `dest` is gone the moment you overwrite it with `stringfinal`.

Anyway, you should be using `std::string` as:

```
std::string string1;
std::string string2;
//...
std::string stringfinal = string1 +"  " + string2;
```

If not `std::string`, you should be using `std::strcpy` and `std::strcat` instead of manual loop, as:

```
char *concat(char *string1,char *string2)
{
    char *stringfinal=new char[strlen(string1)+strlen(string2)+3];
    std::strcpy(stringfinal,string1);                      //^^^ note this!
    std::strcpy(stringfinal, "  ");
    std::strcat(stringfinal,string2);
    return stringfinal;
}
```

Comment: Why so, Nawaz? One can do it with arrays and memcpy, for example.

Comment: I highly suspect this is a basic homework assignment to how how you would concatenate strings, but the `c++` tag confuses me as well in regard to how he's supposed to be doing it.

Comment: @Vlad: I meant, `std::strcpy` and `std::strcat` instead of manual loop!

Comment: thanks...but if I want answer in format "Anurag Jain"???

Comment: @user721995: See the answer. Now it will be "Anurag Jain".

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged your question `c++`:

```
int main()
{
    const std::string str1("Anurag");
    const std::string str2("Jain");
    const std::string strfinal(str1 + str2);

    std::cout << strfinal;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately your code has many problems. I'm really not sure where to start.

How about I just outline what you *should* be doing?

- create new character array with `new` large enough to hold both strings and a terminating `\0`.
- iterate through `string1` copying each character to new array
- iterate through `string2` copying each character to new array
- return new array.

However, since you're using c++, I would suggest using actual strings. What you have above is really C with `new`

**Edit:** In addition, you don't allocate space *outside* of the call, you store it in a pointer:

```
char *strfinal = concat(str1,str2);
```

Comment: thanks...but if I want answer in format "Anurag Jain"???

Answer (score 0):

```
char *stringfinal=new char[strlen(string1)+strlen(string2)+2];
stringfinal=string1;
```

You acquired memory from the free store of size `strlen(string1)+strlen(string2)+2`. Probably an extra 2, I assume for space and a terminating character. And in the next statement, you are making `stringfinal` to point to `string1`, causing a memory leak. The memory acquired through previous `new` statement is laid on the free way which no one has access to. And the same with next statements too.

```
char *dest=new char[strlen(string1)+strlen(string2)+2];
dest = stringfinal;
```

So, finally `dest` is pointing to the location what `string1` <s>which in turn is pointing to read only locations</s> is pointing to. And you are trying to modify the read-only location with the statement -

```
*dest = ' '; // Point 1
```

which is what causing the crash.

---

```
char *str1="Anurag";
char *str2="Jain";
```

Both `str1, str2` are pointing to read only locations and you are passing them as parameters to `concat` function. Also every `new` should be associated with `delete/delete[]` and in your case it is `delete[]`.

Comment: thanks...but if I want answer in format "Anurag Jain"???

Answer (score 0):

Man what was with all those Memory Allocations, drived me nuts, here's your working code, little bit of change was needed:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>

using namespace std;

char * concat(char *string1,char *string2,char *stringfinal)
{

          char *p = stringfinal;

          while(*(p++)=*(string1++)); 
          p--;
          *p=' '; 
          p++;
          while(*(p++)=*(string2++));

                    return stringfinal;
}

int main()
{

    char *str1="Anurag";
    char *str2="Jain";
    char *stringfinal=new char[strlen(str1)+strlen(str2)+2];
    stringfinal=concat(str1,str2,stringfinal);
    cout << stringfinal << endl;

}
```

Comment: thanks....it really helped...But if I want answer in for "Anurag Jain"....how to proceed????

Answer (score 0):

First of all this is wrong:

```
stringfinal=string1;
```

It doesn't do what you think it does, instead use strcpy(stringfinal, string1)
Second, it's not a good programming approach to move your pointer because you would lose your starting point. Instead you may copy it to another pointer and increment the copy.
What you're trying to do (and I'm assuming you wanna concat string all by yourself) may be done in the following manner

```
char* dest = new char[strlen(str1)+strlen(str2)+1];
int i=0;
while(str1[i] != '\0')
{
    dest[i] = str1[i];
    i++;
}
int j=0;
while(str2[j] != '\0')
{
    dest[i] = str2[j];
    i++;
    j++;
}
dest[i] = '\0';
return dest;
```

Comment: thanks...but if I want answer in format "Anurag Jain"???

Comment: Then: in the first line do +2, and in between loops, before or after j=0, write: str[i++] = ' '